# Group similar names together using a python algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I need help on a project I have where I have a list of names referring to multiple products but some names refer to the same product just written in a different way (ex below) what's the best way to classify the most similar names hat are most likely referring to the same product in groups

Example
just one product could be named like this:

-EXFORGE 5 MG/160 B/28 COMP

-EXFORGE 5MG /160 Bte 28

-EXFORGE COMP 5 MG _160 B / 28

-Exforge 5 MG 160 B/28 COMP.

Tried FuzzyWuzzy library but it didn't give me a good result
this was what I did

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

# Assuming 'data' is your column of product names in tabular data
data = [
    'EXFORGE 5 MG/160 B/28 COMP',
    'EXFORGE 5MG /160 Bte 28',
    'doliprane 500MG',
    'dolipran 5.0 MG',
    'EXFORGE COMP 5 MG _160 B / 28',
    'Exforge 5 MG 160 B/28 COMP.',
    'Doliprane 500MG Comp',
    'EXFORGE CP.PEL 5MG/ 160 MG 28',
    'Ciprofloxacine 500 MG/5 ML IV 100 ML Solution for Infusion',
    'CIPROFLOXACINE 500MG/5ML IV 100 ML Sol for Inf',
    'Ciprofloxacine Sol for Infusion 500 MG/5 ML 100 ML',
    'CIPROFLOXACINE 500 MG/5 ML IV 100 ML Sol for Infusion',
    'Ciprofloxacine 500 MG IV 100 ML Sol for Inf',
    'Paracetamol 500 MG Tab 30s',
    'PARACETAMOL 500MG Tab 30s',
    'Paracetamol Tab 500 MG 30s',
    'PARACETAMOL Tab 500 MG 30s',
    'Paracetamol 500 MG 30s Tab',
    'Lisinopril 10 MG Tab 28s',
    'LISINOPRIL 10MG Tab 28s',
    'Lisinopril Tab 10 MG 28s',
    'LISINOPRIL Tab 10 MG 28s',
    'Lisinopril 10 MG 28s Tab',
    'Simvastatin 20 MG Tab 100s',
    'SIMVASTATIN 20MG Tab 100s',
    'Simvastatin Tab 20 MG 100s',
    'SIMVASTATIN Tab 20 MG 100s',
    'Simvastatin 20 MG 100s Tab',
    'Omeprazole 20 MG Caps 28s',
    'OMEPRAZOLE 20MG Caps 28s',
    'Omeprazole Caps 20 MG 28s',
    'OMEPRAZOLE Caps 20 MG 28s',
    'Omeprazole 20 MG 28s Caps'
]

# Define a threshold for similarity
threshold = 87

# Initialize groups list
groups = []

# Function to add similar names to a group
def add_to_group(group, name):
    for existing_name in group:
        if process.extractOne(existing_name, [name])[1] >= threshold:
            return True
    return False

# Iterate through data to form groups
for name in data:
    added = False
    for group in groups:
        if add_to_group(group, name):
            group.add(name)
            added = True
            break
    if not added:
        groups.append({name})

# Print the groups of most similar names
for idx, group in enumerate(groups, 1):
    print(f"Group {idx}: {group}")
```

and got just 3 groups instead of 7 and when I adjusted the threshold to just 88 instead of 87 it went 10 groups

Comment: You should post what you've tried and what results you got. Maybe it's a matter of using the library differently.

Comment: Just to confirm, since you're measuring by text editing distance: should `Paracetamol 500 mg` and `Paracetamol .500 mg` be in the same group, since it's just one character off? What are the expected groups in your example? You might need to add some data normalization, like expanding abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

I would use following heuristic, first use [`.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) method of `str`, then take longest word, that is

```
data = [
    'EXFORGE 5 MG/160 B/28 COMP',
    'EXFORGE 5MG /160 Bte 28',
    'doliprane 500MG',
    'dolipran 5.0 MG',
    'EXFORGE COMP 5 MG _160 B / 28',
    'Exforge 5 MG 160 B/28 COMP.',
    'Doliprane 500MG Comp',
    'EXFORGE CP.PEL 5MG/ 160 MG 28',
    'Ciprofloxacine 500 MG/5 ML IV 100 ML Solution for Infusion',
    'CIPROFLOXACINE 500MG/5ML IV 100 ML Sol for Inf',
    'Ciprofloxacine Sol for Infusion 500 MG/5 ML 100 ML',
    'CIPROFLOXACINE 500 MG/5 ML IV 100 ML Sol for Infusion',
    'Ciprofloxacine 500 MG IV 100 ML Sol for Inf',
    'Paracetamol 500 MG Tab 30s',
    'PARACETAMOL 500MG Tab 30s',
    'Paracetamol Tab 500 MG 30s',
    'PARACETAMOL Tab 500 MG 30s',
    'Paracetamol 500 MG 30s Tab',
    'Lisinopril 10 MG Tab 28s',
    'LISINOPRIL 10MG Tab 28s',
    'Lisinopril Tab 10 MG 28s',
    'LISINOPRIL Tab 10 MG 28s',
    'Lisinopril 10 MG 28s Tab',
    'Simvastatin 20 MG Tab 100s',
    'SIMVASTATIN 20MG Tab 100s',
    'Simvastatin Tab 20 MG 100s',
    'SIMVASTATIN Tab 20 MG 100s',
    'Simvastatin 20 MG 100s Tab',
    'Omeprazole 20 MG Caps 28s',
    'OMEPRAZOLE 20MG Caps 28s',
    'Omeprazole Caps 20 MG 28s',
    'OMEPRAZOLE Caps 20 MG 28s',
    'Omeprazole 20 MG 28s Caps'
]
def get_name(full_name):
    return max(full_name.casefold().split(), key=len)
names = [get_name(i) for i in data]
print(names)
```

gives output

```
['exforge', 'exforge', 'doliprane', 'dolipran', 'exforge', 'exforge', 'doliprane', 'exforge', 'ciprofloxacine', 'ciprofloxacine', 'ciprofloxacine', 'ciprofloxacine', 'ciprofloxacine', 'paracetamol', 'paracetamol', 'paracetamol', 'paracetamol', 'paracetamol', 'lisinopril', 'lisinopril', 'lisinopril', 'lisinopril', 'lisinopril', 'simvastatin', 'simvastatin', 'simvastatin', 'simvastatin', 'simvastatin', 'omeprazole', 'omeprazole', 'omeprazole', 'omeprazole', 'omeprazole']
```

Observe that whilst it counteract various cases (lower, upper, title) but does not counter spelling errors. Keep in mind it might fail for very short names.